# What does ,= mean in python?

Tags: python, operators

I wonder what `,=` or `, =` means in python?

Example from matplotlib:

```
plot1, = ax01.plot(t,yp1,'b-')
```

Comment: @ArnabDatta No ya' can't; that'd be a 2-tuple. You can write `(plot1,) = ...` or `[plot1] = ...`, though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's a form of tuple unpacking. With parentheses:

```
(plot1,) = ax01.plot(t,yp1,'b-')
```

`ax01.plot()` returns a tuple containing one element, and this element is assigned to `plot1`. Without that comma (and possibly the parentheses), `plot1` would have been assigned the whole tuple. Observe the difference between `a` and `b` in the following example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return (1,)
... 
>>> (a,) = foo()
>>> b = foo()
>>> a
1
>>> b
(1,)
```

You can omit the parentheses both in `(a,)` and `(1,)`, I left them for the sake of clarity.

Comment: This seems to be version specific. To be precise you could mention that it is not possible e.g. in Python 2.7 ("ValueError: too many values to unpack"). In addition: why can't I `x,,,=(1,2,3,4)`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller 1) the example above works in Python 2.7, that error means the tuple you are trying to unpack is larger than the number of variables provided in the lhs. 2) you can't because it's not valid syntax. If you want to keep only the first element, then do `x, _, _, _ = (1,2,3,4)`, where `_` is a regular variable name, conventionally used to signal a _"don't care about this value"_. Anyway, I guess `x = foo[0]` is clearer in this case.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo in python 3 you can do [`x, *_ = (1,2,3,4)`](https://asmeurer.github.io/python3-presentation/slides.html#8)

Answer (score 17):

Python allows you to put tuples on the left hand side of the assignment.
The code in the question is an example of this, it might look like it's a special case of an operator but it's really just a case tuple assignment going on here. Some examples might help:

```
a, b = (1, 2)
```

which gives you `a = 1` and `b = 2`.

Now there's the concept of the one element tuple as well.

```
x = (3,)
```

gives you `x = (3,)` which is a tuple with one element, the syntax looks a bit strange but Python needs to differentiate from plain parenthesis so it has the trailing comma for this (For example `z=(4)` makes z be the integer value 4, not a tuple). If you wanted to now extract that element then you would want to use something like you have in the question:

```
y, = x
```

now `y` is 3. Note that this is just tuple assignment here, the syntax just appears a bit strange because it is tuple of length one.

See this script for an example: http://ideone.com/qroNcx

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `,` after a variable places it in a tuple with a single element. This tuple is then assigned a value (with the `=` operator) returned from `ax01.plot(t,yp1,'b-')`.